# Find data: Number of households by income level per U.S. state?

Tags: data, united-states

Do you by any chance know an online source, where I can find the number of households by income level per U.S. state?

I have been going through all of the U.S. census data, but I only can find total US number of households by income level or median household by state.

Comment: This may be better suited for https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The US Census Bureau's [American Fact Finder](https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml) website has what you want.

[Here](https://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/15_5YR/B19001/0100000US.04000) are the state-level household counts by pre-determined income ranges, from the 2011-2015 American Community Survey 5-year dataset.